# What CPUs are supported with Arduino?

Tags: arduino, atmel

Is there a table summarizing the differences of CPUs supported by Arduino? What's the lowest power Atmel processor that can be used with an Arduino?

Comment: This is certainly a programming-related question.  I'm writing an Arduino program and I need to make sure that my program will run on all Arduino platforms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps these are too obvious:

The [official hardware page](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Hardware) might be what you're looking for; clicking on any version brings up an overview which elaborates on each variant. There's also [a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arduino_boards_and_compatible_systems) of official hardware on Wikipedia, although it might not be as up to date.

The lowest voltage for any official Arduino MCU is, as far as I know, 3.3 V. I'm not sure about the current; the forum thread *[Minimizing power consumption](http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1273507808/9)* seems to elaborate further.

**(Update by mh)** Based on the table above, the lowest power Arduino-supported chip is the [ATmega168](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/product_card.asp?part_id=3303) with 16 KB flash and 1K SRAM.

Comment: garmen, the Processor column under "Aruduino Board Models" is just what I was looking for... thanks!

Comment: The chart with the Processor column has moved to [List of Arduino boards and compatible systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arduino_boards_and_compatible_systems). I was looking for the same thing as Mark.

Comment: Thanks for that info Trygve - I updated the link in the answer.